# Apollo GraphQL fails to invoke resolver for a nested field

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I've the following structure in my schema:

```
type gn_Feature implements Some_Interface {
  s_description: String
  s_id: URL!
  some_parent: gn_Feature
}
```

As you can see, each `gn_Feature` has an another linked `gn_Feature` object (the linking is handled elsewhere, it doesn't really matter). By my current understanding, you only need to define the resolvers for the return ***types***, so my resolvers look like the following:

```
export const resolvers = Object.assign(
  {},
  {
    DateTime: DateTime,
    Date: DateTime,
    Time: RegularExpression("Time", /^\d{2}:\d{2}(:\d{2})?$/),
    URL,
    Query: {
       gn_Feature: gn_FeatureResolver
    },
    gn_Feature: gn_FeatureResolver
  }
);
```

But, my queries fail with the following error if I don't explicitly define the resolver for the *nested* field, like so:

`gn_Feature: {some_parent: gn_FeatureResolver}`

Error:

> "message": "Resolve function for \"gn_Feature.s_description\"
>   returned undefined"

My resolver function doesn't even get invoked for my nested object when I don't specify it like the above.
My backend consists of some voodoo transpiling of GraphQL queries into SparQL queries which return data back so I won't post the resolver code as I utilize one universal resolver for many fields. I'd like to avoid having to specify resolvers for each nested field as that's going be extremely tedious (I have dozens of types with dozens of fields). Any clarifications are welcome, as I'm completely baffled.

Example GraphQL query:

```
gn_Feature(some_field:"AD", last:2){
  s_description,
  s_id
  some_parent{
    s_description 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When executing a query, only the value of any particular field is initially unknown and needs to be **resolved**... everything else, like the types, selection sets, etc. is already known. A resolver is a function called to resolve a specific field. In GraphQL.js, there are no resolvers for types.

Apollo muddies the waters a bit in this regard, since for convenience, the API for `makeExecutableSchema` allows you to define custom scalars by including them in the resolver map. Additionally, even though interfaces and unions don't have resolvers either, Apollo lets you use the resolver map to specify a `__resolveType` function for these abstract types as well. Apollo's docs actually define a resolver as "a function that connects schema fields and types to various backends." However, in the context of GraphQL in general, you should think of a resolvers as "a functions that resolves the value of a field".

So, given a type called `gn_Feature` and a field called `some_parent`, this **is** the correct way to structure your resolvers:

```
const resolvers = {
  gn_Feature: {
    some_parent: someResolverFunction
  }
}
```

Also note that `Query` and `Mutation` are both types themselves, so if you have a query called `gn_Feature`, you are actually resolving a field called `gn_Feature` for the `Query` type.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, I was fearing that's the only way..

Comment: May be a question of approaching your schema differently, but hard to know without seeing it and the sort of data you're working with.